# Enable BrowsableAPIRenderer only for admin/specific user

Tags: django-rest-framework

here is my settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}
```

I'm trying to somehow only let admin user access `BrowsableAPIRenderer` so if any other user tries to visit my site that user should see `JSONRenderer`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restrict Django Rest Framework browsable API interface to admin users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507211/how-to-restrict-django-rest-framework-browsable-api-interface-to-admin-users)

Comment: Thanks for the response but this question is so old I can't even remember why I asked it