# How to disable the browsable API for non staff users (is_staff=False)?

Tags: django-rest-framework

in my case I am using Django REST Framework (DRF) as internal api. it is not intended to be consumed by regular users. therefore I would like to disable it for regular users.

an admin (`is_staff=True`) should be able to access it and see it:
https://restframework.herokuapp.com/
[image]

a non staff user (`is_staff=False`) should just get the JSON response of a GET request like:
https://restframework.herokuapp.com/?format=json
[image]
he should **not(!)** see the browsable api. this applies for the root view and all endpoints.

to configure this, I applied the following:

```py
# settings.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ['rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ['rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'],
}
```

my endpoints are the following (to keep the example simple I just show 1):

```py
# api/urls.py
from django.urls import include, path

from rest_framework import routers

from . import views

app_name = 'api'

router = routers.DefaultRouter()  # browseable api
router.register('segments', views.SegmentViewSet)
# there are a lot more...

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

based on answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58894198/420953 my `settings.py` looks like this:

```py
# settings.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ['rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ['rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'],
    # enable JSON renderer by default
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ],
}
```

and my `api/views.py`:

```py
# api/views.py

from django_filters import rest_framework as drf_filters
from rest_framework import filters, renderers, viewsets

from . import serializers
from segment.models import Segment

class StaffBrowsableAPIMixin:
    def get_renderers(self):
        """
        add BrowsableAPIRenderer if user is staff (regular users see JSONRenderer response)
        """
        # explicitly set renderer to JSONRenderer (the default for non staff users)
        rends = [renderers.JSONRenderer]
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            # staff users see browsable API
            rends.append(renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer)
        return [renderer() for renderer in rends]

class SegmentViewSet(StaffBrowsableAPIMixin, viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Segment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SegmentSerializer
```

this works fine for all endpoints (when a regular user calls the endpoint via GET, they only see the JSON, not the browsable API). Unfortunately it does not work for `APIRootView` (the root view of the api, e.g. https://restframework.herokuapp.com/).

how to get this to work for `APIRootView` as well?

Comment: What result you're getting?

Comment: Could you please check the user you're logging in has the attribute is_staff set to true or false?

Comment: regular users (`is_staff=false`) can still navigate to the browsable API (which I would like to prevent).

Comment: And in the browsable api check are you logged in as a normal user or an admin user

Comment: I am using a regular user (and would not like to see the browsable API).
my understanding is that `APIRootView` is the default basic root view for DefaultRouter (which you have to use for browsable API) -> https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py#L291

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507211/how-to-restrict-django-rest-framework-browsable-api-interface-to-admin-users

Comment: thank you Aashay! exactly what I was looking for. missed this post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can lock the base URL of your API down pretty simply (the mixin should probably be moved to another file but just kept everything together for clarity):

```py
# api/urls.py
from django.urls import include, path

from rest_framework import permissions, renderers, routers

from . import views

app_name = 'api'

class StaffBrowsableAPIMixin:
    def get_renderers(self):
        """
        add BrowsableAPIRenderer if user is staff (regular users see JSONRenderer response)
        """
        # explicitly set renderer to JSONRenderer (the default for non staff users)
        rends = [renderers.JSONRenderer]
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            # staff users see browsable API
            rends.append(renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer)
        return [renderer() for renderer in rends]


class CustomAPIRootView(StaffBrowsableAPIMixin, routers.APIRootView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)


class CustomDefaultRouter(routers.DefaultRouter):
    APIRootView = CustomAPIRootView

router = CustomDefaultRouter()  # browseable api
router.register('segments', views.SegmentViewSet)
# there are a lot more...

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

The `permission_classes` will handle not showing any of your endpoints to non-Admin users but the Browsable API template will still be shown.  To remove that as well, you need to change the renderer using the `StaffBrowsableAPIMixin`.

---

#### Original Answer

One way to do this is using DRF's renderer settings and methods.

In your `settings.py`:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Only enable JSON renderer by default.
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ],
}
```

And in your `views.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import generics, renderers

class StaffBrowsableMixin(object):
    def get_renderers(self):
        """
        Add Browsable API renderer if user is staff.
        """
        rends = self.renderer_classes
        if self.request.user and self.request.user.is_staff:
            rends.append(renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer)
        return [renderer() for renderer in rends]

class CustomListApiView(StaffBrowsableMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    List view.
    """
    # normal stuff here
```

Basically, use `StaffBrowsableMixin` for any `APIView` you want the BrowsableAPI to be enabled for staff.

Similar question, as linked above in comments, and my answer there as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58762483/4599228

Comment: do you also know how how to apply this to APIRootView?

Comment: @udo can you update your question to include your `urls.py` and how you tried to use your custom `APIRootView` you wrote above? I can then update my answer to (hopefully) suit your needs.

Comment: I rephrased the question. hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: :) wrong understanding regarding your last edit. no worries. to clarify: all(!) users have permission to access the API. it's just the **browsable API** which has to be restricted to staff users.

Comment: @udo yes, realized after posting so deleted by comment :)  I re-edited, check it out and let me know if that works.