# Stop coreapi displaying the admin api docs

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently documenting the API I have created for an app.

I'm using the built in documentation system that comes with Django Rest Framework and coreapi (as described [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/)).

```
class MyAPI(APIView):

    schema = ManualSchema(fields=[coreapi.Field(...), ...],
                          description='Describe this view')
```

I set up the url for the docs in the urls.py for the API app:

```
url_patterns = [
    url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls('My API Title')),
    ...
]
```

The problem I have is that when I visit the docs I see the admin API docs alongside my API docs.

I've tried using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898065/how-to-disable-admin-style-browsable-interface-of-django-rest-framework):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}
```

But the admin docs still show up.

Is there a way to hide the admin docs?

Comment: have you tried http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#patterns ?

Comment: Given I define the schema in the `APIView` class, I'm not sure where the `schema_url_patterns` would go.